# How to correct obtain HWND from SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl2, urho3d

I use Urho3D which uses SDL2 as a window system. I want create another window as GUI and make it child for main window of Urho3D.

What I did is:

```
// insde virtual void Start() // Urho3D app
SDL_Window * sdlw = context->GetSubsystem<Graphics>()->GetWindow();
int width = context->GetSubsystem<Graphics>()->GetWidth();
int height = context->GetSubsystem<Graphics>()->GetHeight();
HWND mw = SDLWindows::GetWindowHWND(sdlw);
wpfC = WPFI::CreateWPFControl(0, 0, width, height);
HWND www = SetParent(wpfC, mw); // SetParent is windows function
if (www == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "------------------------------\n"
        << "www = NULL\n"
        << GetLastError() << "\n"
        << "------------------------------\n";
}
```

---

```
HWND SDLWindows::GetWindowHWND(SDL_Window * wnd)
{
    SDL_SysWMinfo sysInfo;
    SDL_VERSION(&sysInfo.version);
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(wnd, &sysInfo);
    return sysInfo.info.win.window;
}
```

---

I got `Invalid window handle (1400) Error on SetParent()`.

I am not sure if I am doing it right, but I am sure that my `wpfC` is ok because I have another test project where it is working but instead SDL window I use win32 Window.

I think `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo()` give me a wrong handle.

Question is how to obtain `HWND` from `SDL_Window` correctly and be sure that it is right `HWND`?

If it is not possible do it that way, is there another way how to create child window from `HWND` inside main SDL2 window?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for Invalid window handle.

I edit source code of Urho3D engine and create function

```
void *GetSDLWindowHWND()
HWND hWnd = static_cast<HWND>(context->GetSubsystem<Graphics>()->GetSDLWindowHWND());
```

after that, SetParent() function working and my window child is displayed in Urho3D main window.